# Prevent display of titles, email address and date on Fullpage slides or sections

Tags: wordpress, fullpage.js

I've installed Fullpage as a plugin.  I use Wordpress with the Optimizer Pro theme.

I had hoped to use Fullpage to build page content from a blank screen within Wordpress, but Fullpage is displaying slide titles, my email address, the date and a shaded text box as some sort of default on every section of slide, whether I have tried to put content on the page or not.  How do I get rid of all the content Fullpage seems to default to, so that I can create my own page?

Warning:  I am a neophyte self-taught web developer, so I may be missing something obvious.  Thanks.

Comment: You can see the pages at http://www.wilsonconsult.net/?page_id=76#fullpage-section-2

Comment: Seems like a question for the wordpress plugin creator ? Fullpage.js doesn't add anything in your content by default.

Comment: Are you not the plugin creator?

Comment: Yeah, I'm the creator of fullpage.js, but not of the Wordpress theme.